# Codeigniter db->get() returns empty recordset

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model

My table `user` is as follows:

```
    | user_id | first_name | moniker     |
    |       1 | Noah       | noahsarkive |
    |       2 | Homer      | HomerK      |
    |       3 | Hot        | Inflated    |
    |       4 | Wimpy      | Wimpy B     |
    |       5 | Hubble     | SharpEyes   |
```

The model is User_model.php:

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class User_model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function get_users() {
    $this->db->select('user_id','first_name', 'moniker');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    var_dump($rs);
    return $rs;
}
}
```

but when I do a `var_dump($rs)` it yields:

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#25 (8) {
  ["conn_id"]=>
  resource(25) of type (mysql link persistent)
  ["result_id"]=>
  resource(36) of type (mysql result)
  ["result_array"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["custom_result_object"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["current_row"]=>
  int(0)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(5)
  ["row_data"]=>
  NULL
}
```

It returns the correct number of rows but no data!
Couldn't be simpler, but I must be missing something very obvious.

I appreciate your help. 
Noah

Comment: $rs = $this->db->get()->result();

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with the result object, [like so](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html):

```
$rs = $this->db->get();
foreach ($rs->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->user_id;
   echo $row->first_name;
   echo $row->moniker;
}
```

Comment: but there's nothing to echo. the result set is empty. note   ["result_array"]=>
  array(0) {
  }

Comment: IIRC, those are empty wrappers to class calls, so a dump won't show it.  Try simply altering your code to `var_dump($rs->result_array());` and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_users() 
{
    $this->db->select('user_id ,first_name , moniker');//fix your select function like this
    $this->db->from('user');
    $rs = $this->db->get()->result();
    var_dump($rs);
    return $rs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was a corrupted DB. Dropped the schema and restored it, then all ran OK.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,it will help you.

```
public function get_users()
{
    $this->db->select('user_id','first_name', 'moniker');
    $this->db->from('user');
     $info = $this->db->get();
    if($info->num_rows() > 0)
    {
      return $info->result();
    }
    else
    {
      return NULL;
}
```